# How to fix the error like Do not contain a definition of "Contains" for adding the search bar in List View

Tags: xamarin, search, xamarin.forms

I tried to add a search bar in the ListView but it failed.

after clicking debug the program, it shows the error like "does not contain a defination for "Contains" ... in the part of code behind

I would like to for help for this. Thanks

in the code behind :

```
public partial class ListPage : ContentPage
{
    public ListPage()
    {

        InitializeComponent();

        listView.ItemsSource = LoadData();

 private void SearchBar_Pressed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

       var keyword = MainSearchBar.Text;

       listView.ItemsSource = LoadData().Where(name => name.Contains(keyword));
```

}

```
//in the following codes is about the function LoadData() 
which includes the information in the ListView
```

it is expected that I can search the keyword in the search bear how the error is "Error CS1929: 'Video' does not contain a definition for 'Contains' and the best extension method overload 'Enumerable.Contains(IEnumerable, string)' requires a receiver of type 'IEnumerable' (CS1929) (MVDemo)"

Please help for it. Thanks

---

Yes, ok, thanks, let me post other parts in this program. For the LoadDate(),  The code behind is :

```
     #region "LoadData"
        protected IList<Video> LoadData()
        {
            var videos = new List<Video>();
            videos.Add(new Video
            {
                ID = "27/items/Final_201903/心相契合Final.mp4",
                Name = "心相契合",
                Writer = "璞園詩歌",
                Photo = ImageSource.FromFile("Heart.png")
            });
            videos.Add(new Video
            {
                ID = "2/items/20191006_769/明光照耀.mov",
                Name = "明光照耀",
                Writer = "璞園詩歌",
                Photo = ImageSource.FromFile("Light.png")
            });

            return videos;
        }
        #endregion
```

in the xaml:

```
   <StackLayout>
    <SearchBar x:Name="MainSearchBar" SearchButtonPressed="SearchBar_Pressed"/> 
<ListView IsPullToRefreshEnabled="True"  x:Name = "listView"     ItemTapped="Handle_ItemTapped" HasUnevenRows="true" SeparatorVisibility="Default">
      <ListView.ItemTemplate>
          <DataTemplate>
              <ImageCell Text="{Binding Name}"
                        Detail="{Binding Writer}"
                        ImageSource="{Binding Photo}"/>


          </DataTemplate>

      </ListView.ItemTemplate>

      </ListView>

    </StackLayout>
```

I made the page for the class "Video" in file "Models" , the code is:

```
public class Video
{
    public Video()
    {

    }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public ImageSource Photo { get; set; }
    public string Writer { get; set; }
    public string ID { get; set; }


}
```

Please help me for it. In fact, I'm new in the Xamarin. Thanks

Comment: What is the return type of `LoadData`?

Comment: Please provide the `view modetl with data of listiew` and the `LoadData()` for us to test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to filter the Name, please try the code below.

**Change:**

```
listView.ItemsSource = LoadData().Where(name => name.Contains(keyword));
```

**To:** The Name is what you defined in Video class.

```
listView.ItemsSource = LoadData().Where(name => name.Name.Contains(keyword));
```

I make the sample to test, it works well on my side.

**Result:**

[image]

Answer (score 0):

your LINQ query has a syntax error

```
listView.ItemsSource = LoadData().Where(x => x.name.Contains(keyword));
```